# how to take out the average in a single query and also checking the average greater than certain value and arranging in ascending order

Tags: sql-server-2005

Display average basic salary for each department and include only those employees who are having more than 20 years age? And display only those departments for which average basic salary is more than 5000? Then sort the output in the ascending order of average basic salary?

plz tell me a single query for this statement

Thanks,
Churchill

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
SELECT t.Dept,t.Salary 
FROM (SELECT Dept,AVG(Salary) AS Salary
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Age > 20
GROUP BY Dept)t
WHERE t.Salary > 5000
ORDER BY t.Salary ASC
```